# How to send a Message with discord.py

Tags: python, function, pycharm, discord, discord.py

## Hello

#### The Problem:

I am currently trying to program my own discord bot. but somehow i just cant figure out how to make him send messages by himself.

#### What i have already tried

i have figuerd out how he can send messages as response but i want him to send a message by himself as soon as he is running.

#### what i am trying to achieve

i was trying to find an answer on google or youtube but i just couldnt find anything.

im really just a beginner and im happy for all the help i can possibly get =)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure to read the guideline for posting questions. One key igredient is to show that you have tried to solve the problem on your own. Share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like a message to be sent as soon as the bot is running, try the on_ready() built-in function. I'm not sure how you are doing the discord bot, as discord.py supports a couple different ways, but if you are using a custom wrapper class for the discord.Client then the on_ready event is the way to go.

You should also check out the documentation for event references at [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference)
as it has a lot of helpful code snippets and examples spread throughout.

Assuming you are using a wrapper class, the on_ready event will look something like this:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')
        await self.get_guild(your-guild-id).get_channel(your-channel-id).send("your-message")
```